# entity framework query not working when searching on date add days

Tags: entity-framework

In entity framework 5 if I do this

```
context.customers.Where(x => x.delDate >= DateTime.Now
```

this works fine and brings back records

however if I do this

```
context.customers.Where(x => x.delDate >= EntityFunctions.TruncateTime(DateTime.Today.AddDays(2))
```

always brings back zero.

I want to bring back all customers that have a delDate of more than today plus 2 days.    It should bring back records as they do exist.

Comment: it brings back 0 or it raises an error ?

Comment: Thanks, yes I tried that but it does not bring back records.    If I use DateTime.Now it works fine but not if I use EntityFunctions.TruncateTime(DateTime.Today.AddDays(2))

Comment: No it brings back zero and I know that records do existe

Comment: EntityFunctions.TruncateTime() will be translated into da DB function, so try doing something like this: `context.customers.Where(x => EntityFunctions.TruncateTime(x.delDate) >= DateTime.Today.AddDays(2).Date)`

Answer (score 0):

You want the `DateTime.Date` method, which returns the date with time set to midnight:

```
context.customers.Where(x => x.delDate >= DateTime.Today.Date.AddDays(2));
```